# The type 'MarshalByRefObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to make a **C# Console Application** using **.NetCore** on **"Visual Studio 2017"** for the sake of running it on **CentOS 7**, what seems to be the issue is that apparently the .NetCore doesn't have some of the Classes that's inside the .Net Framework, or that's what I think the problem is.
So I've tried adding a reference to assembly **mscorlib** but that just made the errors even more..

> Error CS0433  The type 'StringBuilder' exists in both 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Any idea how can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

[.NetCore Console Application using Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGOXl.png)

Answer (score 1):

MarshalByRefObject is not part of .NetCore so you should not use it.

Scroll to comments and you will find info and link about replacement.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/making-it-easier-to-port-to-net-core/